# Pass equals symbol into a string

Tags: vbscript

VBScript is not really my thing, but having a dabble.

Basically I have a script that will look in a text file that contains a set of machine names, will then check to see if a service is running, if so stop and disabled it, if not running check if its enabled then disabled it. Logging out the start state and the end state.

Trying to enhance script to be able to do the reverse - ie: enable and start.
These will be run from windows scheduled task, so wanted to just pass in a parameter of say "On" or "Off"

So something like this at the top:

```
Function Toggle
    If UCase(WScript.Arguments(0)) = "ON" Then  states = "Running" End If 
    If UCase(WScript.Arguments(0)) = "OFF" Then  states =  "Running" End If 
    If UCase (WScript.Arguments(0)) = "ON" Then symbol = " = " End If
    If UCase (WScript.Arguments(0)) = "OFF" Then  symbol = " <> " End If 
End Function
```

But further down when I try to use these to compare the status of the service using:

```
If InStr(objProcess.DisplayName,strService) > 0 And objProcess.State & symbol & states  Then Status = True
```

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Typemismatch: '[string: "Stopped = Running"]'

If I comment out the symbol variable and use the `=` symbol, the comparison works.

Is it possible to pass in `=` or `<>` into a string for comparison?

Tried using `cstr` around all the variables but this made no difference.

Comment: You're trying to evaluate a string as a Boolean (`objProcess.State & symbol & states`). `&` is a concatenation symbol.

Comment: Also, in your code above you've got both `ON` and `OFF` states as "Running".

Comment: Hi, yeah i know, really is the symbol variable that is the important one as it will be used to pass in whether the check will be = or <> running. Can think of other ways to do the script, was just wondering why this way wasnt working, as would be less typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting the issue, is as described previously, you're actually trying to perform a Boolean operation on a concatenated string.

You can get around this one of two ways - the (almost) *good* way and the **evil** way - your choice...

### GOOD

Write a small processor to evaluate the strings...

```
If symbol = "=" Then...
```

### EVIL

[(May your soul boil in hell for all eternity...)](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/)

Don't believe the hype - if you plan properly and clean your strings properly you should be fine.

`Eval` is the key, or, rather in VBScript's case, [`Execute`](https://ss64.com/vb/execute.html).

Just be very careful - it is **open to abuse**.

also, your situation may not actually be suited to `Execute`.  You may need to use the first or 'Good' option above.

Comment: Cheers Paul. Think I will just use two separate procedures. One to stop and disable, one to enable and stop - based on the command line parameter. Thanks for taking the time to show me the error of my ways and save me some wasted effort!